# Which each to use?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is my understanding that the following two uses of each do the same thing. Is one preferred over the other?  My objective it to create a table with the returned data.  Thanks

```
$.get('getList.php',
function (data)
{
    $.each(data, function(i, value) {console.log(value);})
    $(data).each(function(){console.log(this);});
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {console.log(data[i]);}
    for (i in data) {console.log(data[i]);}
},'json');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that `data` will be a JS object and not a DOM element you should use:

```
$.each(data, ...
```

Because `$.each()` is intended as a generic iterator over any object or array.

The `$(data).each(...` syntax is intended to iterate over DOM elements contained in a jQuery object. If you create a jQuery object containing `data` and `data` is not an array I think you'll find that `$(data).each(...` will run one iteration that returns the whole object rather than one iteration per property. If `data` is an array it will iterate over the elements, but it's not really the intended use.

Using `for (i in data)` is fine if `data` is not an array (if it is an array you should use a standard `for` loop not a `for..in`), but since you're using jQuery anyway you might as well stick with `$.each()` unless there is a performance concern.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  I marked it up, and will give it the best answer as long as it remains the best answer.

Comment: One nice thing about `$.each` is that it doesn't have the old "closure in a `for` loop" problem that causes so much confusion.

Comment: @muistooshort - True. But if we solved that problem StackOverflow would go out of business.